# Recuperar datos de variable sessionStorage desde un script

Tags: javascript, variables, session, javascript-objeto, storage

tengo un problema, basicamente tengo que recuperar un valor de sessionStorage para cambiar el valor de una variable.

Tengo una pagina de navegador con un camvas y unos botones, los cuales disparan unos juegos:

En las funciones he puesto alert para ver si entraba, no es relevante.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="890" height="590"></canvas>

    <button  onclick="loadScript('LASERV1Partida/GameLaser.js',function(){alert('de momento se quea')})">boton1</button>
    <button  onclick="loadScript('REPARACIONESV1Partida/GameRepairs.js',function(){alert('y de momento se quea tambien')})">boton2</button>
```

A continuación continuo el script y añado lo siguiente. inicio session storage con los valores de unas variables, hago unos console log para ver cuanto valen y comprobarlo.

```
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('structure',10);  //modificando recursos de estructura
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('health',5);  //modificando recursos de estructura
        console.log("estructura inicial"+window.sessionStorage.getItem('structure').valueOf()); //modificando recursos de estructura)
        console.log("salud inicial"+window.sessionStorage.getItem('health').valueOf()); //modificando recursos de estructura)
```

a continuacion, cuando se desarrolla el juego, se establecen unas condiciones de victoria y derrota, si la victoria se produce no sucede nada, pero si se produce una derrota las variables que están en window.sessionStorage son modificadas:

```
    function Fracaso(){
                    if(Derrota==true){
                        alert("MISSION FAILED\nTOO MUCH DAMAGE");
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem('structure',window.sessionStorage.getItem('structure').valueOf()-1);  //modificando recursos de estructura
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem('health',window.sessionStorage.getItem('health').valueOf()-1);    //modificando recursos de estructura}
```

Si hago console.log veo que los valores se han cambiado, es decir, en el script de fracaso() veo que console.log me define nuevo valor para los valores de sessionStorage.

La problemática y el asunto es que tengo que cambiar el valor de variables desde el html donde llamo al script, que tiene unas variables declaradas y estas tienen que tomar el nuevo valor de sessionStorage modificado (que en este caso, al ser fracaso, valen 1 unidad menos).

¿cómo hago ese paso?

Comment: Los juegos que ejecutas los has creado tu? o tienes alguna documentación de lo que estas ejecutando

Comment: si, los he creado yo, claro, de hecho esa acción de tomar las variables están en la función fracaso, que reduce puntos de recursos varios.

Comment: Por que no utilizar cookies?

Comment: Estoy intentando hacerlo, pero no logro que funcione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está resuelto, bastaba con tomar un elemento del html por su id y pasarle el valor de session, no era necesario hacer ni un listener, ni cookies ni nada por el estilo, entre otras cosas porque el div está en la misma ventana de navegador.